# Removing default grouping in Kendo Grid

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to implement react kendo grid from [this](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/grouping/grouping/) example from Kendo. I see that one column is grouped by default. I am trying to implement grouping but without one default column grouped already. How can I load data without default grouped column?

I tried

```
 state = this.createAppState({
        take: 10,
        group: [ { field: '' } ]
    });
```

Also Tried

```
 state = this.createAppState({
        take: 10,
        group: []
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the group to an empty array it will initialize a grouping without a default grouped column - here is an example that worked correctly at my side - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ynzwm7-thwt8x?file=app/main.js .

Answer (score 1):

Your second snippet is almost correct, but you are missing the `skip` property:

```
state = this.createAppState({
    skip: 0,
    take: 10,
    group: []
});
```

Without it you would get the message "No records available". Alternatively also remove the `take` property and it will work too:

```
state = this.createAppState({
    group: []
});
```